# Base64 encoding, DONT_BREAK_LINES option

Tags: base64

I am using Base64.encodeBytes to encode by signed data, but it adds new line character to the generated string (for every 76 characters).
I found out that there is an option to pass `DONT_BREAK_LINES` to avoid new line chars.

But the description of this fields says  `/** Don't break lines when encoding (violates strict Base64 specification) */`

Can someone please explain, why using this option violates Base64 spec ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term Base64 originated from [MIME content transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Transfer-Encoding).

The latest version of the RFC that defines this is [here, RFC 5322](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322.txt).

It says:

```
2.1.1.  Line Length Limits

   There are two limits that this specification places on the number of
   characters in a line.  Each line of characters MUST be no more than
   998 characters, and SHOULD be no more than 78 characters, excluding
   the CRLF.
```

And since CR and LF are each one character, that leaves 76 characters for the lines.

TBH it only violates the *suggestion* of the text and really nobody cares. If you had a line longer than 996 characters, then you would be in violation .. and probably nobody would care.